# Find the base vectors of a point set

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, peak-detection

I have a list of coordinates that fits into a 2D periodic lattice, with some error ( $\vec{R}=n\vec{i}+m\vec{j}+\vec{\varepsilon}$). Is there a way to find the base vectors of the lattice? I guess the goal is to find $\vec{i}, \vec{j}$ that minimizes $\sum|\vec{\varepsilon}|^2$, with some penalties on $\vec{i}, \vec{j}$ being too short. I don't know if this is a well-researched problem. $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ are almost perpendicular to each other, if it helps.

```
SeedRandom[127];
i = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2];
j = RotationMatrix[π/2 + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]].i;
p = RandomSample[Table[a i + b j + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, 2], {a, 0, 9}, {b, 0, 9}]~
Flatten~1, 60];
```

[image: Graphics[Point@p]]

Answer (score 4):

My solution is basically what I said above, but I feel that it's not the optimal way to do it

```
fit = NMinimize[Total[Table[
      With[{px = {{Cos[θ], Cos[ϕ]}, {Sin[θ], 
      Sin[ϕ]}}.pi}, Norm[px - Round[px]]^2], {pi, 
 p}]], {θ, ϕ}, Reals];


(*{{-0.454011, 0.890996}, {0.872185, -0.489176}}*)
Normalize /@ Inverse[{{Cos[θ], Cos[ϕ]}, {Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]}} /. fit[[2]]] 


(*{{-0.855362, -0.51803}, {0.446033, -0.895016}}*)
Normalize /@ {i,j}
```

Comment: Contrary to your feeling, I find this approach exceptionally elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Here I add a solution with only one parameter to minimize. Basically it's the same idea @arax showed in his answer.

Knowing $ i, j $ to be perpendicular you only need to find an optimal [`Rotationmatrix`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotationmatrix.html) `R`:

```
R = RotationMatrix[φ] 
J = Total @ Map[(δ = R.# - Round[R.#]; δ.δ) &, p];
opt = NMinimize[J, φ] 
(*{6.09196, {φ -> -0.449484}}*)


Graphics[{Point[p], Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, R[[1]]} ], Arrow[{{0, 0}, R[[2]]}]} /. opt[[2]]]
```

[image]